# C++ static member initiazation

Tags: c++

I am trying to add literal for bitset.

```
namespace std {

template <size_t, char...> struct bitset_literal_factory;

template <size_t N, char... cs>
struct bitset_literal_factory<N, '0', cs...> { static bitset<N> value; };

template <size_t N, char... cs>
bitset<N> bitset_literal_factory<N, '0', cs...>::value =
                  bitset_literal_factory<N, cs...>::value;

template <size_t N, char... cs>
struct bitset_literal_factory<N, '1', cs...> { static bitset<N> value; };

template <size_t N, char... cs>
bitset<N> bitset_literal_factory<N, '1', cs...>::value =
                  bitset_literal_factory<N, cs...>::value.set(sizeof...(cs));

template <size_t N>
struct bitset_literal_factory<N, '0'> { static bitset<N> value; };

template <size_t N>
bitset<N> bitset_literal_factory<N, '0'>::value = bitset<N>();

template <size_t N>
struct bitset_literal_factory<N, '1'> { static bitset<N> value; };

template <size_t N>
bitset<N> bitset_literal_factory<N, '1'>::value = bitset<N>().set(0);

namespace bitset_literal {
/* big end */
template <char... cs> bitset<sizeof...(cs)> inline operator""_bs()
{
    return bitset_literal_factory<sizeof...(cs), cs...>::value;
}

}

}
```

This works well when using gcc, but when i use clang, i got all zero.(e.g. `00111000101_bs`)

I thought this may be a problem about static member initialization order. And then i got that static member initialized in the order that they are defined in. So i try another example:

```
struct bar {
    static int i; 
};

struct foo {
    static int i; 
};

int foo::i = ++bar::i;

int bar::i = 1;   

int main() 
{
    std::cout << foo::i << ' ' << bar::i << std::endl; 
}
```

This time both gcc and clang print `2 2`. So is this a bug in clang, or is this my fault because the order of `bitset::set`'s execution is undefined?

Comment: Don't put your stuff in `namespace std`. That belongs to the standard library implementation.

Comment: Adding your own items to `namespace std`, other than specializations of templates that already exist, causes undefined behaviour.  Once you have fixed that, if the problem still occurs, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which produces unexpected output.

Comment: The second example is well-defined because *constant initialization* happens before *dynamic initialization*.  `int bar::i = 1;` is constant initialization because `1` is a constant initializer.

Comment: @PeteBecker @M,M This is just a test, i have another bitset in my own namespace, and this problem occurs, so i test it for bitset in namespace `std`. Actually, other identifiers in `std` is start with charactor `_`

Comment: @M.M Thank you, i changed it from `int bar::i = 1` to `int bar::i = std::time(0)`, this time the value of `foo::i` becomes `1`.

Comment: In that case `foo::i` initialization is sequenced before `bar::i` dynamic initialization, so `1` is the expected value.  This all has not much to do with initialization of objects of class type though.